# Java passing lambda as argument with properties

Tags: java, interface, lambda

I am trying to create an object which has two parts, a string and a method. For my handling of this I want the user to be able to do add(Instance) or add(string, lambda).

The way I understand it, I can't use an interface because they don't have public only properties (Not static), I can't use a class because then I couldn't pass it as an argument and I can't pass an interface then call the method directly because that would be bad practice.

So how / what is the best way to do this?

EG:

```
interface IFoo {
    void DoBar();
}

class Foo implmenets IFoo {
    public string Bar;
}
```

EG add:

```
void addFoo(Foo foo) {
     this.foos.add(foo);
}

void addFoo(String bar, IFoo foo) {
    foo.Bar = bar;
    this.foos.add(foo);
}
```

EG usage:

```
addFoo("yes", () -> {
    //some code
});
```

EDIT: My current solution, feels like it would be bad practice, but it's the best I can come up with until someone else has a better idea.

Interface (For the Lambda to use)

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ICommand
{
    void processCommand(CommandArgument[] args);
}
```

Class (For instancing)

```
public abstract class Command implements ICommand
{
    public String command = "";

    public abstract void processCommand(CommandArgument[] args);
}
```

Add method

```
public void addCommand(String commandName, ICommand action) {
    Command command = new Command() {
        @Override
        public void processCommand(CommandArgument[] args) {
            action.processCommand(args);
        }
    };
    command.command = commandName;

    this.addCommand(command);
}
```

Usage:

```
CommandHandler handler = new CommandHandler();
handler.addCommand("quit", (CommandArgument[] args) -> System.exit(0));
```

Comment: I think only interfaces that are tagged with the `@interface FunctionalInterface` annotation, can be instantiated with lambdas.

Comment: You'll have to use a class, but that class can have a constructor that takes a string and a lambda.

Comment: You may want to rethink how you're representing this data. Most people, when calling a method like `addFoo("key", myFoo)` would not expect properties to get set on the value that they pass in. This could cause all kinds of unexpected behavior if they try to pass the same instance in with different strings. Maybe you should *not* have `Foo` implement `IFoo`, and have your overloaded method create a new `Foo` instance, whose implementation calls the given lambda's action?

Comment: That's what I've ended up doing for the time being, creating an instance with a method that just calls an interface method feels so wrong though.

Comment: @mike A functional interface is any interface with a Single Abstract Method (aka. a SAM type). The annotation is optional.

Comment: @user1763295 can we see that code?  That sort of sounds fine.

Comment: Yeah sure, I've added it now for you.